# Grails: situation where .validate() works but .save() will fail

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm

If a domain class will validate can I be assured it will save (assuming nothing super-drastic like the database is down)?  More explicitly, under which scenarios will an object pass validation but throw an error on save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> under which scenarios will an object pass validation but throw an error on save.

Domain class constraints can check anything, so if "the thing they check" changes between the calls to `validate()` and `save()`, then it's entirely possible that the former will succeed and the latter fails.

Here's a very simple such example

- `Book.ISBN` has a unique contraint
- `myBook.validate()` is called and passes
- another book with the same ISBN as `myBook` is saved
- `myBook.save()` fails because the unique constraint on ISBN now fails

Answer (score 3):

Save will throw an error if your database has additional constraints that don't allow the insert or update to succeed. If your database doesn't have any additional constraints and barring any sort of infrastructure outages, I can't think of any reason `save()` would fail if `validate()` is true.

Comment: To expand on 'additional constraints' things to keep in mind are data type, data size, foreign key relationships, non null constraints, permission (the app doesn't have permission to write to the table(s), nextval a sequence etc.).  Those have all bitten me in the past.  +1 for doelleri and Don both are good valid answers.